# Ant -v doesn't give correct information

Tags: ant

When executing the command `ant -v`, it gives me the error:

> Apache Ant(TM) version ${project.version} compiled on ${TODAY}.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The Ant source code shows where these non-referenced properties come from:

```
$ cat src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/version.txt
VERSION=${project.version}
DATE=${TODAY}
```

These properties are supposed to be expanded when the Ant binaries are built with `ant jars`.

Are you trying to use a version of Ant you built yourself?

The [official binaries from Apache](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: what jar files are associated with the version.txt file?

Comment: @jdoe08 Version info is stored in ant.jar. If you open the ant.jar archive (with 7-Zip on Windows, for example), the version info is stored in `org/apache/tools/ant/version.txt`.